# Turn Off loopback audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

Me and other friends who use ubuntu noticed an annoying problem, when we are in a meeting (meet, slack, teams, etc.) if someone listens to any audio or video on the computer, this sound is sent through the person's microphone, so everyone can hear what the person is listening to, I've researched a lot about it and I can't find anything that allows me to turn off this audio feedback, I've used alsamixer, etc. and I haven't found any option to turn this problem off, we all use headphones with microphones that have the P3 connector

Comment: If you are in a meeting why are they listening to something else? What have you tried and etc is not an answer. What version of Ubuntu.

Comment: why they are listening to something while they are in a meeting is not the issue, we all use ubuntu 20.04